# Gnuplot, how to *skip* missing data files?

Tags: gnuplot

Depending on various factors i may not have 1 or more data files, referenced in pre-defined gnuplot plot instructions, that don't exist. When this is the case i get *"warning: Skipping unreadable file"* which cancels the rest of the instructions.

Is there any way i can ask gnuplot to skip any missing data files and plot all of the existing ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to do this without a simple helper script.  Here's my solution with the "helper":

```
#!/bin/bash
#script ismissing.sh.  prints 1 if the file is missing, 0 if it exists.
test -e $1
echo $?
```

Now, make it executable:

```
chmod +x ismissing.sh
```

Now in your gnuplot script, you can create a simple function:

```
is_missing(x)=system("/path/to/ismissing.sh ".x)
```

and then you guard your plot commands as follows:

```
if (! is_missing("mydatafile") ) plot "mydatafile" u 1:2 ...
```

**EDIT**

It appears that gnuplot isn't choking because your file is missing -- The actual problem arises when gnuplot tries to set the range for the plot from the missing data (I assume you're autoscaling the axis ranges).  Another solution is to explicitly set the axis ranges:

```
set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [-1:1]
plot "does_not_exist" u 1:2
plot sin(x)  #still plots
```

Comment: Hmm... i believe you are right. Your solution for the missing data files is quite good tho for other stuff i was planning on doing. thanks a lot.

Comment: I was actually very surprised that the script bailed out as the interpreter issued a warning, not an error -- Good question.

Comment: @mgilson If ones xrange and yrange are updating every iteration, then it might be a good idea to plot the file conditionally. I had a similar problem given http://stackoverflow.com/q/19461549/842808.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a similar solution without a helper script

```
file_exists(file) = system("[ -f '".file."' ] && echo '1' || echo '0'") + 0
if ( file_exists("mydatafile") ) plot "mydatafile" u 1:2 ...
```

the `+ 0` part is to convert the result from string to integer, in this way you can also use the negation

```
if ( ! file_exists("mydatafile") ) print "mydatafile not found."
```

Comment: Modern gnuplot also accepts `int(system("[ -f '".file."' ] && echo '1' || echo '0'"))`