# Skipping empty files in Gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, skip, is-empty, isnullorempty

I am using `gnuplot 4.6`. Also, I know that a similar question was asked more than a year ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610625/gnuplot-how-to-skip-missing-data-files). The answer to that requires to write a small `bash` script. I want to know if it is possible to achieve this from within `gnuplot` script, especially when `gnuplot-4.6` has so many cool features added. I am trying to achieve something like this :

```
set xrange[xL:xU]
set yrange[yL:yU]
plot "file1.dat" using 1:2 w l lt 1 lw 1 lc 3,\
"file2.dat" using 1:2 w l lt 1 lw 1 lc 3
```

I am repeating the above process in a loop and the `xrange` & `yrange` parameters are being updated in each iteration. Also, I am saving the output of each iteration as some image file. Now, `file2.dat` is guaranteed to have some points in all iterations. BUT this is NOT true for `file1.dat`. Hence, I want `gnuplot` to skip plotting the `file1.dat` in case it is empty. Please note, that it is PERFECTLY OK in my case if no points are plotted from `file1.dat`.

This can be achieved easily using an `if` statement, provided there is some command in `gnuplot` to detect if a file has no points, without trying to plot it. In that case, the above code will look something like this :

```
set xrange[xL:xU]
set yrange[yL:yU]
if ("file.dat" not empty){
plot "file1.dat" using 1:2 w l lt 1 lw 1 lc 3,\
    "file2.dat" using 1:2 w l lt 1 lw 1 lc 3
}else {
plot "file2.dat" using 1:2 w l lt 1 lw 1 lc 3
}
```

Please help me formulate the `'condition'` of the aforementioned `if` statement.

Thanks & Cheers

Abhinav

Comment: It is still not possible to check with gnuplot-only methods if a file exists. You need some kind of helper script to do this. But why is it a problem? The plot command would issue a warning and thats it.

Comment: it is a problem as even though one file has no in-range points, I still want to plot the other file which does have the in-range points.

Comment: You are right! I thought that the `plot` command only skips the missing file, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any hack that used only `gnuplot` commands. As a result, I am posting a work around which takes the help of `shell` to find if `file1.dat` has any any lines of data or not.

The condition in the `gnuplot` script file will look like :

```
if(system("awk '{x++}END{ print x}' file1.dat")>0){
    plot "file1.dat" using 1:2 w l lt 1 lw 1 lc 3,\
    "file2.dat" using 1:2 w l lt 1 lw 1 lc 3
}else{
    plot "file2.dat" using 1:2 w l lt 1 lw 1 lc 3
}
```

I still would be grateful if anyone can give me a `gnuplot` command only method.