# How to read in irregularly numbered data files in script to make gnuplot images?

Tags: if-statement, gnuplot, skip, continue

I have a script (called: *anim.sh*) to read in my simulation data, plot each data file in gnuplot, and save each as a .gif file. The data is named: ***g000000, g000007, g000008, g000010***....etc. My script reads in these 4 data files and makes a plot in gnuplot, then saves the output as a .gif file. My question is how do I read in this irregularly numbered data? I have:

```
do for [i=0:3] {
str_num=sprintf('%03d',i)  #Write integer to string
set term gif
set output 'my_output.'.str_num.'.gif'
set xr [-0.2:0.2]
set yr [-0.2:0.2]
plot 'g000'.str_num w d
}
```

This would work fine if my files were called *g000000, g000001, g000002, g000003* but they are not! so I get an error:

```
line 8: warning: Skipping unreadable file "g000001"
line 8: No data in plot
```

How do I add to the code to skip missing files (e.g. g000001 - g000006) and continue the loop?

p.s. In reality i have hundreds of files and not just 4 so I don't want to rename them by hand.

Comment: What you've quoted above isn't a `bash script` for sure.

Comment: Apologies, I should just have said "script" and not "bash script". The code is saved as anim.sh and I run it in linux with >gnuplot anim.sh

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gnuplot, how to \*skip\* missing data files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610625/gnuplot-how-to-skip-missing-data-files)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate of that question!

Comment: @Christoph: At least very similar then, the accepted answer would  work here.

Comment: @Thor Right, the questions are only *similar*, and although the other answer works, for this question here a better solution exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a list of all files and iterate over them:

```
set terminal gif
set xrange[-0.2:0.2]
set yrange[-0.2:0.2]

filelist = system('ls g00*')
do for [file in filelist] {
    set output 'my_output.'.(file[2:*]).'.gif'
    plot file
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Christoph. Worked Perfectly!

Comment: Hi @Christoph. I also have different data files named s000000, s000007, s000008, s000010...etc. How would I over-plot these (i.e. plot g000000 and s000000) in the same .gif file?

Comment: If you always have `g...` and `s...` file pairs, then you can use `filelist = system('ls g00* | tr -d "g"')` and later inside the loop use `plot 'g'.file, 's'.file`.

Comment: Thanks @Christoph. And what if I don't have g... and s... file pairs, but my second batch of files were called 'name_no'. for e.g. star000000, star000007 etc?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that. You mean you have star000000 instead of s000000?